# Sharing columns with pivot_longer multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I need to pivot_longer multiple variables matching a specific pattern: "crt_variable_1" and "crt_variable_3" plus "peso_1" and "peso_3"

I picked 2 variables matching crt_ with _1 and _3 respectively. I want "crt_ppara_01", "crt_ppard_01", "crt_ppara_03", "crt_ppard_03" need to be separated names to "gen" and values to "Ct" and the time indicator "_1" and "_3" to a column time. On the other hand, "peso_1", and "peso_3", values should go to a column named "peso" and time indicator ("_1 or "_3") to "time" column.

The code I tried give me an error because doing it  in 2 steps, time columns cannot absorb time indicator of "peso_". And with regular expression I couldn't handle to do it.

```
#2 steps
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("crt_"), names_to = c("gen", "time"), 
               names_sep = "_", values_to = "Ct") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("peso_"), names_to = c("peso", "time"), 
               names_sep = "_", values_to = "peso")


#regular expression

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = matches("^(crt|peso)_"), 
               names_to = c("type", "gen", "time"), 
               names_pattern = "^(crt|peso)_(.+)_?(\\d+)?", 
               values_to = "value", 
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  separate(type, into = c("type1", "type2"), sep = "_") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = type2, values_from = value)
```

The data example to reprex

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(140102089, 70802013, 60901027, 60901020, 
120715021, 70802015, 140103026, 60901026, 140101097, 60901028
), crt_ppara_01 = c(21.456, 19.785, 20.889, NA, NA, 19.395, 18.783, 
18.802, 19.999, 20.455), crt_ppard_01 = c(18.085, 16.623, 18.037, 
16.744, 16.59, 17.335, 15.53, 17.096, 16.916, 18.512), crt_ppara_03 = c(19.518, 
20.76, 20.642, NA, 18.123, 20.799, 19.817, NA, 20.838, 20.251
), crt_ppard_03 = c(16.461, 17.755, 17.516, 17.176, 15.626, 18.172, 
15.795, 16.582, 17.571, 17.499), peso_1 = c(70, 78.2, 91.2, 84.3, 
76.2, 100, 81.4, 82.2, 65.1, 108), peso_3 = c(69.7, 71.7, 86.9, 
83.7, 76, 100, 80, 77, 64, 116.9)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The desired output

```
id  time    peso    gen    Ct
A1  1          x    ppara   y
A2  1          v    ppard   z
A3  3          h    ppara   j
A4  3          k    ppard   l
```

EDIT1 :
This is happening in the first step, with my database. It's repeating with each id, it is duplicating rows, without "time" values. There can be NAs in the values columns, but in the time column there shouldn't be

```
genes  %>%
pivot_longer(!c(id, sexo, edad0, grup_int), names_pattern = "(.*)_0*([0-9]+)$", names_to = c(".value", "time"))
```

As you can see 50109018 has 2 more rows without values.

```
# A tibble: 6 × 61
        id sexo  edad0 grup_int time   peso crt_ppara crt_ppard crt_pparg crt_nr1h3 crt_nr1h2 crt_rxra
     <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <fct>    <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 50109018 1        76 3        NA     NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA  
2 50109018 1        76 3        NA     NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA  
3 50109018 1        76 3        1      63.2      21.0      18.2      25.7      22.4      18.7     15.1
4 50109018 1        76 3        3      63.5      18.3      16.8      23.8      21.0      18.2     13.8
5 50109019 0        80 3        NA     NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA  
6 50109019 0        80 3        NA     NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
```

I`m adding a small df2 to illustrate what is happening

```
df3 <-df2 %>% pivot_longer(!c(id, sexo, edad0, grup_int), names_pattern = "(.*)_0*([0-9]+)$", names_to = c(".value", "time"))


df2 <- structure(list(id = c(140103027, 140103027, 140103027, 140103027, 
130106038, 130106038, 130106038, 130106038, 70111024, 70111024, 
70111024, 70111024, 71801001, 71801001, 71801001, 71801001, 50203030, 
50203030, 50203030, 50203030, 50203006, 50203006, 50203006, 50203006, 
50203011, 50203011, 50203011, 50203011, 60901021, 60901021, 60901021, 
60901021, 50202099, 50202099, 50202099, 50202099, 71801003, 71801003, 
71801003, 71801003, 70802015, 70802015, 70802015, 70802015, 140102095, 
140102095, 140102095, 140102095, 60901026, 60901026, 60901026, 
60901026, 111201026, 111201026, 111201026, 111201026, 140103020, 
140103020, 140103020, 140103020, 140102088, 140102088, 140102088, 
140102088, 50508026, 50508026, 50508026, 50508026, 120715011, 
120715011, 120715011, 120715011, 50203004, 50203004, 50203004, 
50203004, 50203027, 50203027, 50203027, 50203027), sexo = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", 
"1", "9"), class = "factor"), edad0 = c(76, 76, 76, 76, 70, 70, 
70, 70, 63, 63, 63, 63, 66, 66, 66, 66, 65, 65, 65, 65, 60, 60, 
60, 60, 59, 59, 59, 59, 55, 55, 55, 55, 78, 78, 78, 78, 73, 73, 
73, 73, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 75, 75, 75, 75, 62, 62, 
62, 62, 66, 66, 66, 66, 60, 60, 60, 60, 74, 74, 74, 74, 66, 66, 
66, 66, 79, 79, 79, 79, 64, 64, 64, 64), grup_int = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), time = c(NA, NA, "1", "3", NA, 
NA, "1", "3", NA, NA, "1", "3", NA, NA, "1", "3", NA, NA, "1", 
"3", NA, NA, "1", "3", NA, NA, "1", "3", NA, NA, "1", "3", NA, 
NA, "1", "3", NA, NA, "1", "3", NA, NA, "1", "3", NA, NA, "1", 
"3", NA, NA, "1", "3", NA, NA, "1", "3", NA, NA, "1", "3", NA, 
NA, "1", "3", NA, NA, "1", "3", NA, NA, "1", "3", NA, NA, "1", 
"3", NA, NA, "1", "3"), peso = c(NA, NA, 52.9, 50.5, NA, NA, 
88.3, 83.3, NA, NA, 71, 69.4, NA, NA, 81.5, 80.8, NA, NA, 81.4, 
86.1, NA, NA, 64.2, 63.2, NA, NA, 90, 97.2, NA, NA, 95, 97.7, 
NA, NA, 62.6, 64, NA, NA, 71.1, 67.5, NA, NA, 100, 100, NA, NA, 
87, 86.3, NA, NA, 82.2, 77, NA, NA, 76.7, 74.4, NA, NA, 76.9, 
73, NA, NA, 68.8, 73.6, NA, NA, 60.6, 62.1, NA, NA, 102, 100, 
NA, NA, 60.9, 50.8, NA, NA, 72.9, 71.1), crt_ppara = c(NA, NA, 
20.309, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19.306, NA, NA, NA, 19.788, 
NA, NA, NA, 19.587, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.687, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19.093, NA, NA, NA, 21.078, NA, NA, NA, 19.395, 
NA, NA, NA, 19.796, NA, NA, NA, 18.802, NA, NA, NA, 19.556, NA, 
NA, NA, 20.612, NA, NA, NA, 21.625, NA, NA, NA, 20.173, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.332, NA), crt_ppard = c(NA, 
NA, 17.4, NA, NA, NA, 17.089, NA, NA, NA, 16.741, NA, NA, NA, 
16.957, NA, NA, NA, 17.27, NA, NA, NA, 18.317, NA, NA, NA, 17.783, 
NA, NA, NA, 17.76, NA, NA, NA, 17.095, NA, NA, NA, 18.446, NA, 
NA, NA, 17.335, NA, NA, NA, 17.243, NA, NA, NA, 17.096, NA, NA, 
NA, 17.269, NA, NA, NA, 17.291, NA, NA, NA, 18.597, NA, NA, NA, 
16.811, NA, NA, NA, 17.084, NA, NA, NA, 19.624, NA, NA, NA, 16.813, 
NA), crt_pparg = c(NA, NA, 23.312, NA, NA, NA, 24.123, NA, NA, 
NA, 22.73, NA, NA, NA, 23.82, NA, NA, NA, 22.889, NA, NA, NA, 
25.73, NA, NA, NA, 24.357, NA, NA, NA, 25.556, NA, NA, NA, 23.564, 
NA, NA, NA, 25.568, NA, NA, NA, 24.702, NA, NA, NA, 23.08, NA, 
NA, NA, 24.088, NA, NA, NA, 23.596, NA, NA, NA, 22.301, NA, NA, 
NA, 26.63, NA, NA, NA, 23.193, NA, NA, NA, 23.485, NA, NA, NA, 
26.947, NA, NA, NA, 23.993, NA), crt_nr1h3 = c(NA, NA, 21.51, 
NA, NA, NA, 21.701, NA, NA, NA, 20.216, NA, NA, NA, 22.409, NA, 
NA, NA, 22.065, NA, NA, NA, 22.761, NA, NA, NA, 22.669, NA, NA, 
NA, 22.599, NA, NA, NA, 22.507, NA, NA, NA, 22.918, NA, NA, NA, 
21.915, NA, NA, NA, 21.59, NA, NA, NA, 21.894, NA, NA, NA, 21.743, 
NA, NA, NA, 21.639, NA, NA, NA, 23.248, NA, NA, NA, 22.24, NA, 
NA, NA, 21.787, NA, NA, NA, 23.672, NA, NA, NA, 21.801, NA), 
    crt_nr1h2 = c(NA, NA, 17.476, NA, NA, NA, 18.272, NA, NA, 
    NA, 17.228, NA, NA, NA, 18.476, NA, NA, NA, 18.562, NA, NA, 
    NA, 19.671, NA, NA, NA, 18.773, NA, NA, NA, 19.29, NA, NA, 
    NA, 18.531, NA, NA, NA, 19.325, NA, NA, NA, 18.738, NA, NA, 
    NA, 17.963, NA, NA, NA, 18.529, NA, NA, NA, 18.138, NA, NA, 
    NA, 18.444, NA, NA, NA, 19.229, NA, NA, NA, 18.76, NA, NA, 
    NA, 17.72, NA, NA, NA, 20.274, NA, NA, NA, 17.931, NA), crt_rxra = c(NA, 
    NA, 12.826, NA, NA, NA, 14.389, NA, NA, NA, 13.224, NA, NA, 
    NA, 13.817, NA, NA, NA, 15.591, NA, NA, NA, 15.351, NA, NA, 
    NA, 14.656, NA, NA, NA, 14.666, NA, NA, NA, 14.61, NA, NA, 
    NA, 14.711, NA, NA, NA, 14.596, NA, NA, NA, 14.365, NA, NA, 
    NA, 13.866, NA, NA, NA, 13.803, NA, NA, NA, 14.269, NA, NA, 
    NA, 15.81, NA, NA, NA, 15.446, NA, NA, NA, 13.837, NA, NA, 
    NA, 16.464, NA, NA, NA, 14.521, NA), crt_rxrb = c(NA, NA, 
    16.629, NA, NA, NA, 17.52, NA, NA, NA, 16.264, NA, NA, NA, 
    16.585, NA, NA, NA, 18.039, NA, NA, NA, 18.017, NA, NA, NA, 
    17.554, NA, NA, NA, 16.839, NA, NA, NA, 17.652, NA, NA, NA, 
    17.558, NA, NA, NA, 16.831, NA, NA, NA, 16.62, NA, NA, NA, 
    16.821, NA, NA, NA, 17.82, NA, NA, NA, 17.742, NA, NA, NA, 
    18.054, NA, NA, NA, 18.307, NA, NA, NA, 16.837, NA, NA, NA, 
    19.034, NA, NA, NA, 17.628, NA), crt_cyp27a1 = c(NA, NA, 
    17.765, NA, NA, NA, 16.89, NA, NA, NA, 16.753, NA, NA, NA, 
    17.013, NA, NA, NA, 17.609, NA, NA, NA, 19.67, NA, NA, NA, 
    18.941, NA, NA, NA, 17.681, NA, NA, NA, 19.249, NA, NA, NA, 
    18.258, NA, NA, NA, 17.827, NA, NA, NA, 18.047, NA, NA, NA, 
    18.697, NA, NA, NA, 17.641, NA, NA, NA, 17.466, NA, NA, NA, 
    19.294, NA, NA, NA, 17.708, NA, NA, NA, 18.66, NA, NA, NA, 
    19.675, NA, NA, NA, 18.009, NA), crt_abca1 = c(NA, NA, 17.096, 
    NA, NA, NA, 18.731, NA, NA, NA, 17.003, NA, NA, NA, 16.649, 
    NA, NA, NA, 19.168, NA, NA, NA, 19.253, NA, NA, NA, 18.688, 
    NA, NA, NA, 18.668, NA, NA, NA, 18.44, NA, NA, NA, 17.937, 
    NA, NA, NA, 17.942, NA, NA, NA, 17.83, NA, NA, NA, 16.868, 
    NA, NA, NA, 19.163, NA, NA, NA, 18.687, NA, NA, NA, 19.88, 
    NA, NA, NA, 18.476, NA, NA, NA, 17.837, NA, NA, NA, 19.5, 
    NA, NA, NA, 16.593, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```r
pivot_longer(df, -id, names_pattern = "(.*)_0*([0-9]+)$", names_to = c(".value", "time")) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("crt_"), names_to = "gen", values_to = "Ct") %>%
  mutate(gen = sub("^crt_", "", gen))
# # A tibble: 40 × 5
#           id time   peso gen      Ct
#        <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#  1 140102089 1      70   ppara  21.5
#  2 140102089 1      70   ppard  18.1
#  3 140102089 3      69.7 ppara  19.5
#  4 140102089 3      69.7 ppard  16.5
#  5  70802013 1      78.2 ppara  19.8
#  6  70802013 1      78.2 ppard  16.6
#  7  70802013 3      71.7 ppara  20.8
#  8  70802013 3      71.7 ppard  17.8
#  9  60901027 1      91.2 ppara  20.9
# 10  60901027 1      91.2 ppard  18.0
# # … with 30 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: This is a really nice code!

Comment: Edited because of some type of error (probably in my database) that I cannot make out