# Why pivot_longer is creating 2 extra rows with NAs?

Tags: r, tidyr, na

I come from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76072383/sharing-columns-with-pivot-longer-multiple-columns) where I asked on how to pivot_longer sharing one column as time indicator, transfering them 2 blocks of variables

Now scalating the code to my database I found that each id has been duplicated adding extra rows with no info at all. There can be NAs in the values of the variables, the dataset contains missing, but why does it have NAs in the time column? Which actually comes from separating variables after pivot_longer

```
# 1st step

df2 <- df %>% pivot_longer(!c(id, sexo, edad0, grup_int), names_pattern = "(.*)_0*([0-9]+)$", names_to = c(".value", "time"))

# what i don't understand is the 2 extra rows with the same id but no values at all  in time, edad0, grup_int. I looked into the code but I am missing something for sure

A tibble: 6 × 15
        id sexo  edad0 grup_int time   peso crt_ppara crt_ppard crt_pparg crt_nr1h3 crt_nr1h2 crt_rxra
     <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <fct>    <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1   1.40e8 1        76 2        NA     NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA  
2   1.40e8 1        76 2        NA     NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA  
3   1.40e8 1        76 2        1      52.9      20.3      17.4      23.3      21.5      17.5     12.8
4   1.40e8 1        76 2        3      50.5      NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA  
5   1.30e8 0        70 2        NA     NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA  
6   1.30e8 0        70 2        NA     NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
```

EDIT:Desired output. As you can see I just have the time 1 and 3. It's not just my expected output, it's I don't how is it possible to obtain the other output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 15
        id sexo  edad0 grup_int time   peso crt_ppara crt_ppard crt_pparg crt_nr1h3 crt_nr1h2 crt_rxra
     <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <fct>    <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1   1.21e8 1        64 3        1      81        19.7      16.1      22.3      20.8      17.6     12.9
2   1.21e8 1        64 3        3      74.5      NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA  
3   1.10e8 0        58 1        1      96.5      20.1      17.4      24.0      21.4      18.8     14.8
4   1.10e8 0        58 1        3      95.2      NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA  
5   1.21e8 1        73 1        1     102        19.7      17.3      23.8      21.9      17.9     14.0
6   1.21e8 1        73 1        3     100.       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
```

This is for reprex

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(120715012, 110110005, 120715020, 120715022, 
111201006, 120715021, 50203031, 71801001, 60901030, 140103023, 
111201017, 60901031, 140102090, 60901020, 110104024, 120715029, 
60901037, 140102089, 50521002, 120715033), sample_name = c("A2582200012000006001", 
"A2571600005000006001", "A2582200020000006001", "A2582200022000006001", 
"A2576000006000006001", "A2582200021000006001", "A2537700031000006001", 
"A2564800001000006001", "A2552500030000006001", "A2592000023000006001", 
"A2576000017000006001", "A2552500031000006001", "A2591900090000006001", 
"A2552500020000006001", "A2571200024000006001", "A2582200029000006001", 
"A2552500037000006001", "A2591900089000006001", "A2542900002000006001", 
"A2582200033000006001"), experiment_name = c("OCW07_2022_04_26_110614.eds", 
"OCW06_2022_04_26_110610.eds", "OCW06_2022_04_26_110610.eds", 
"OCW07_2022_04_26_110614.eds", "OCW09_2022_04_26_132510.eds", 
"OCW07_2022_04_26_110614.eds", "OCW10_2022_04_26_132513.eds", 
"OCW10_2022_04_26_132513.eds", "OCW09_2022_04_26_132510.eds", 
"OCW09_2022_04_26_132510.eds", "OCW08_2022_04_26_132458.eds", 
"OCW10_2022_04_26_132513.eds", "OCW07_2022_04_26_110614.eds", 
"OCW06_2022_04_26_110610.eds", "OCW06_2022_04_26_110610.eds", 
"OCW09_2022_04_26_132510.eds", "OCW10_2022_04_26_132513.eds", 
"OCW09_2022_04_26_132510.eds", "OCW11_2022_04_26_132517.eds", 
"OCW10_2022_04_26_132513.eds"), sexo = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), levels = c("0", "1", "9"), class = "factor"), edad0 = c(64, 
58, 73, 75, 70, 67, 59, 66, 71, 68, 67, 69, 80, 66, 70, 67, 60, 
62, 60, 68), grup_int = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), peso_1 = c(81, 96.5, 102, 68.5, 
77.5, 76.2, 96.9, 81.5, 100, 81.5, 71.7, 82.5, 81.5, 84.3, 98.9, 
73, 63.5, 70, 90.4, 69), peso_3 = c(74.5, 95.2, 100.5, 60, 76.8, 
76, 100.2, 80.8, 111.5, 83, 72.1, 75, 82.5, 83.7, 98.2, 72, 61.5, 
69.7, 91.4, 74.3), crt_ppara_01 = c(19.667, 20.055, 19.719, 20.49, 
20.472, NA, 20.345, 19.788, 19.674, NA, NA, 20.833, 21.253, NA, 
20.337, NA, 21.621, 21.456, NA, 20.315), crt_ppard_01 = c(16.136, 
17.367, 17.296, 17.615, 17.421, 16.59, 17.801, 16.957, 16.692, 
18.922, 15.734, 18.107, 18.579, 16.744, 18.261, 17.758, 18.684, 
18.085, NA, 17.27), crt_pparg_01 = c(22.346, 24.017, 23.806, 
24.849, 24.072, 23.854, 24.749, 23.82, 22.673, 25.671, 22.568, 
25.535, 24.913, 24.563, 24.397, 22.694, 26.475, 25.566, NA, 24.266
), crt_nr1h3_01 = c(20.781, 21.426, 21.912, 22.443, 21.733, 20.831, 
22.83, 22.409, 21.798, 22.66, 20.245, 22.988, 23.366, 22.407, 
22.71, 22.231, 23.703, 22.749, 21.904, 21.676), crt_nr1h2_01 = c(17.571, 
18.75, 17.86, 18.789, 18.273, 18.074, 19.265, 18.476, 18.414, 
19.072, 16.215, 19.595, 20.194, 18.49, 19.191, 18.793, 19.803, 
18.793, 19.236, 18.616), crt_rxra_01 = c(12.869, 14.813, 14.042, 
15.005, 14.551, 14.142, 15.273, 13.817, 14.026, 14.839, 12.942, 
14.864, 15.823, 14.579, 15.578, 14.736, 15.592, 15.261, NA, 14.022
), crt_rxrb_01 = c(16.355, 17.425, 17.643, 17.839, 17.542, 16.662, 
18.546, 16.585, 16.737, 18.415, 18.288, 17.742, 18.724, 17.388, 
17.959, 17.751, 17.886, 17.932, 16.97, 16.805), crt_cyp27a1_01 = c(17.333, 
18.148, 18.788, 19.458, 18.09, 17.025, 18.97, 17.013, 17.578, 
17.713, 16.217, 18.492, 20.224, 18.043, 18.645, 17.758, 19.202, 
19.452, NA, 18.096), crt_abca1_01 = c(17.708, 19.142, 18.271, 
19.261, 18.665, 18.536, 18.252, 16.649, 16.815, 18.781, 16.886, 
18.165, 18.613, 17.79, 19.368, 18.18, 19.612, 18.812, NA, 17.748
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output based on your input example

Comment: Edited. As I said up, I don't really understand which is the mechanism because it's duplicating rows keeping several variables and adding NAs to the others

Comment: It looks like you need to add "sample_name" and "experiment_name" to your list of excluded columns in the `pivot_longer`.

Comment: It works, but I don't really get what is happening there. Long data doesn't contain these columns in the dataset. Furthermore, it makes no sense to me to have NAs in time column

Comment: I had a play around with this last night @JavierHernando, and I'm quite confident (at least part of) the issue is around the name columns. I honestly have no idea why. I think maybe values are being coerced into the wrong formatted columns, and then that is producing NAs, and so those NAs are being recorded as values for a particular ID. I think though this would be a good candidate for whittling down the code and the data while retaining the bugs, to see at what point it goes away.

Comment: As an interim post-pivot hack, you can filter with `df2 <- df2 %>% filter(rowSums(!is.na(pick(-c(id, sexo, grup_int, time, edad0)))) > 0)`. Not sure about the rest, looks like a bug to me.